# Reconciliation library for a banking system

Tags: architecture

Im trying to come up with a design for a reconciliation library that can reconcile data points between master(where are these data points are generated) for different domains against various systems(subscribers that consume these datapoints).

For eg: Say I have 3 different domains customer, accounts and payments. System 1 might be interested in account domain only, System 2 might be interested in all three domains etc.

Within the Reconciliation library (We need to agree between different systems on what attributes are deemed necessary in different domain models)

1. We should be able to configure subscribers and their interested domains in the application.yaml file.
2. The manager should use a separate table for different domains, consume records from these domain topics and calculate hashes of agreed attributes and store the hash value in a db, alongside the event’s key, during write time.
3. Scheduled job is run on the manager every hour to collect a list containing map of event key, list of value hashes for that key, for all events received during the previous hour and broadcast it to interested subscribers based on the configuration.
   (This requires the subscribers to stand up a api for reconciliation.)
4. The subscribers on receiving the request can then run the same hashing algorithms for data on their end and compare with the list of hashes they received, since the hashes are associated with a key, they should be able to easily let us know which ones are out of sync.
5. Master should have a endpoint to receive this information from the subscribers and create a alert for the mismatches.
   since reconciliation uses a timed window, we should also identify a timestamp field within each domain event for ordering and retrieving events based on timestamp

This is my initial design, but I feel like its not comprehensive as I shouldn't be comparing the events on both sides but the state of the system due to these events?
How Can I improve the design any ideas?